# ¿Cómo poner un div ocupando toda la pantalla con un navbar y un footer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Actualmente tengo un problema, y es que tengo en una ventana los siguientes elementos: Un navbar, un cuerpo y un footer. El problema es que el contenido del cuerpo no es suficiente como para que ocupe toda la pantalla y no quede feo. Queda tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo solucionar esto. He probado a usar jquery, restando la altura del navbar y el footer a la de la ventana, pero se ve como un salto cuando realiza esta función y queda feo.

Había pensado en poner en el navbar y el footer un `z-index 1` y en el body un `z-index 2` con un `min-height 100vh`, pero no me funciona...

Alguna idea?

Comment: Dale al body una altura del 100% y pon el margin-top del footer en auto.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido poner una altura del 100% al body... En cuanto a lo del footer, lo que me dijiste no me funcionó, pero me valió para investigar y ver que si pongo   ```position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%; ```, se posiciona abajo del todo siempre. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JuanGracia solo debes agregar al footer la clase [.fixed-bottom](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#fixed-bottom)